# What matrices can be covered with rotations of a stamp?

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, matrices, geometry

When is it possible to "cover" certain parts of a black and white matrix with copies of another? I understood the problem as stamping, where you have a $k\times k$ array that you can use by itself or rotate 90,180,270 degrees then stamp onto the original matrix. Once a square is colored black, it will stay black forever, and a square that has not been touched by ink will stay white. The "canvas" is all white at the start, and we want to see if we can stamp it so that it is identical to the original matrix we want to get. For example, a matrix that looks like this:

```
.**
.**
***
```

can be covered completely with rotations of

```
.*
**
```

Or, is there an algorithm that I can use to confirm if it can be stamped?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: I doubt there an answer when the question is posed in such complete generality.

Comment: @GerryMyerson would there be any type of algorithm to confirm if it is possible or not then?

Comment: For a given target, and a given stamp, it's a finite problem, so of course there is an algorithm to determine whether its possible; just try every one of the finitely many possibilities.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to see whether using the stamp $A$ to ink the target array $B$ is possible, simply check *for all black pixels of $B$* whether $A$ can be positioned and oriented so that it inks that black pixel, but not any white pixel of $B$. For example, it is not possible to ink the left array by stamping the right array below:

```
****
* **
** *    **
****    **
```